# SQl para ORM(sqlalchemy)

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy

Como transformar essa query de sql para orm?

```sql
select cod_quest 
  from questoes a 
  where a.cod_quest not in (
     select cod_questao 
       from respostascurso b 
       where a.cod_quest is null = b.cod_questao 
    and b.grr="grr3123"
  ) 
  order by(a.num_quest);
```

É um questionário, eu preciso acessar a tabela de respostas do usuário e ver qual questão ele ainda não respondeu em order crescente pegar a proxima questão.

Answer (score 0):

resolvido, caso alguém precise segue a resposta.

db.session.query(Questoes.cod_quest).filter(~Questoes.cod_quest.in_(db.session.query(RespostasCurso.cod_questao).filter(Questoes.cod_quest.is_(None)==RespostasCurso.cod_questao, RespostasCurso.grr=="GR1234"))).all()